# Simple jQuery Slider

Tags: javascript

I have to create simple image slider WITHOUT [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and other modules. I can use only custom post type slides.

How can I do that?

Comment: call the js of the slider in your theme's custom js and apply all the data with attributes like <ul><li class = "js_class"><img src = "<?php print $img ?>/images/image.jpg"></li></ul>

Comment: In Drupal modules are the way to go to add functionality. If you are doing it any other way, you are asking for troubles alter. Unless you meant "how to create my own module to provide a slider?", maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the following steps

- Download the **Slider Plugin** and paste required files in your active custom module(*sites/all/modules/custom/yourmodule/js OR sites/all/modules/custom/yourmodule/css*) OR in theme(*sites/all/theme/yourtheme/js OR sites/all/theme/yourtheme/css*) folder.
- Create a new block in youmoudle using **hook_block_info** and **hook_block_view** functions.
- Inside **hook_block_view()** call a function

  ```
  $block['content'] = 'get_slider';
  ```
- **get_slider()** will return the html for the slider. Make sure that the html returned follow the proper structure as mentioned in the Slider Plugin you have chosen. You can find the html example for each slider Plugin, follow the same html structure.
- Add the corresponding JS files using **drupal_add_js** and CSS files using **drupal_add_css**
- JS file is used to initialize the Slider to run.
- Check your browser console to check errors

Answer (score -1):

Just download any slider script, and use how it is using its images to make it slider.

Just follow through these steps:-

1. First paste the html of slider directly on the page
2. Include the necessary files (js/css)
3. Now fetch the images only of custom post type from database to make it dynamic

Slider will automatically start working. 
There can be issues with drupal js and slider js files, so avoid  including unnecessary files.

Comment: *"paste the html of slider directly on the page where you want to show it"* sounds like a recipe for disaster. Finding where parts of HTML came from year later, or when you are taking over someone's else project is really a challenge (at best) if site is created like that.

Comment: @Molot, You can edit the answer rather than adding the comment. That would be better i think.

Comment: No, I can't. It would be a radical edit changing too much of your original content, and that's forbidden. Radical edits are something only the one who posted is allowed to do.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who tried to help me to understand this question. I am really not expected to get -4 for my question... It is weird... I am not drupal developer. I came from WordPress ...